# Processing bounce emails

Tags: php

Say I am sending 1000s of emails using any service provider. Is there any way to know which are the email could not delivered, may be because of wrong email id?

Say I sent an email using gmail service provider to "rohit1234@gmail.com", and say id like "rohit1234@gmail.com" do not exists. So this will not be delivered. How can I know from the service provider that this email did not delivered because of  any reason?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a very broad question and will most likely be closed. You need to provide more information and give a specific problem to answer. There are many methods and services for sending multiple emails you haven't specified what you're using.

Comment: I wanna say most service providers (like Postmark, Sendgrid) typically provide an API to access that information. It returns bounced emails, failures and other errors..

Comment: If you're sending through a script and localhost, you can check your maillogs (such as /var/log/maillog). Parse through them for any line that contains "stat=" and does NOT say 'Accepted' or 'OK'. Take a look at the log to see how the servers send their responses.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is called a "[non-delivery report](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)."

The linked Wikipedia article includes links to and examples from [RFC 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464) (and RFC 6522), which documents a standardized reporting format.  Older mail servers were built before this was standardized upon, so you're going to end up building a *lot* of special-case code for these.   Lotus Notes, older versions of Exchange, and qmail in particular are the worst offenders, and there are a *lot* of them out there.

If you really want to do this yourself, as opposed to using a third-party service as suggested in the comments, then I highly recommend using an existing mail reading library.  I've had some measure of success using [Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html) from version 1.x of the Zend Framework.  It exposes each message and the MIME components within each, which makes detection of the reporting chunk pretty darn straightforward.